# How to use SSL certificate to send XML to URL in C#

Tags: c#

I want to send XML to URL which is SSL certified.I have added SSL sertificates also. But when I run the code, I get an error

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Below is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    namespace VTSDataTransferService
    {
        class VTSDataTransferService
        {
            static void IOCLDataThreadProc()
            {
                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://someurl.com");

                    string XmlStr = "some string";
                    req.KeepAlive = false;
                    req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
                    req.Method = "POST";
                    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XmlStr);
                    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
                    req.ContentLength = XmlStr.Length;

                    X509Certificate cert1 = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Users\\dipaliw\\Desktop\\Certificates\\Im1.cer");
                    X509Certificate cert2 = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Users\\dipaliw\\Desktop\\Certificates\\Im2.cer");
                    X509Certificate cert3 = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Users\\dipaliw\\Desktop\\Certificates\\EnRoot.cer");
                    X509Certificate cert4 = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Users\\dipaliw\\Desktop\\Certificates\\server.cer");

                    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert1);
                    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
                    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert3);
                    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert4);
                    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
                    Stream writer = req.GetRequestStream();
                    writer.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                    writer.Close();
                    HttpWebResponse response;
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                    response.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried with SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 instead of Ssl3?

Comment: yes I have tried that also.

Comment: I'm facing this problem from couple of days. Please help me..